# running a C++ program in Fedora Linux

Tags: c++, g++, fedora

In order to compile a program using the *terminal* in `Fedora Linux`, we do the following:

```
> g++ hello.cpp
```

What should I do in order to **run** the program?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a C program on Ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635794/how-to-run-a-c-program-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Hey Med-SWEng i have not downvoted you, but i can understand the guys, googling this would have brought you directly to a site which covers that topic eg. Google:"compile c++ on linux" first hit is this site  http://arachnoid.com/cpptutor/setup_unix.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll generate a file "a.out" which you can execute as: `./a.out`

Alternatively you can specify the name for your executable using `-o`:

`g++ yourfile.cpp -o myexe`

Comment: After compiling with `g++`, I didn't get an *executable file* why is that?

Comment: Was the compilation successful with `g++ hello.cpp` without errors?

Comment: you'll get the a.out file only if the compilation (g++) was successful.

Answer (score 4):

Default output from g++ is a.out, so to run the program from your example:

```
> ./a.out
```

To instead give a name, use:

```
> g++ hello.cpp -o hello
> ./hello
```

Comment: After compiling with `g++`, I didn't get an *executable file* why is that?